# CocoaPods deintegrate deletes workspace files

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm using Xcode and CocoaPods, and Occasionally when I run `pod deintegrate`, followed by `pod install`, unrelated files in my workspace will be deleted. It happened a few times, and I thought it was due to my accidentally placing project files in the Pods directory, which is not under version control, but it recently happened again where this was for sure not the case. I'm quite stumped as to what is causing this, and I haven't been able to find any previous mentions of this problem online, nor have I been able to reproduce it systematically (though to be sure unsystematically, all too many times).

A guard against this is of course to `git status` and make sure that everything is `git add`-ed before ever deintegrating the workspace, which is good practice anyway, but for large commits it can be hard sometimes to remember exactly which files have been added, and at any rate `git status` will not catch files that for some reason have been dumped into untracked directories.

I realize this is quite vague, but has anyone else experienced something like this? Or has an idea of ways to address it?

**EDIT:** I think I've figured out the cause. Sometimes when I `Cmd + n` to make a new file, the interface will not put the new file in the right *folder* (on the Mac) even though it puts in the right *group* (in Xcode). Taking care to ensure that both the folder and the group match seems to solve it, along with double-checking that the file has an `A` on the Xcode interface to make sure it's been added to version control. The reason `Cmd + n` was behaving differently was that I was invoking it from different places. E.g., if I was invoking it while viewing a file in the Pods group/folder, even if I set the *group* to something else, it would still save in the Pods *folder*.

Comment: Definitely a problem specific to your setup. First of all any "untracked directories" should be something you don't need for build to work correctly, or otherwise you are introducing some invisible dependencies (someone cloning the repo will not have these files for sure). So either you need to add them to github, or not worry that they are getting deleted.
Secondly, anything that `pod deintegrate && pod install` changes, except for `Podfile` and `Podfile.lock` should not be under version control either. For example `.xcworkspace` and its contents should always be local, not in repo.

Comment: Thank you. I think I've figured out the cause. Sometimes when I ```Cmd + n``` to make a new file, the interface will not put the new file in the right _folder_ (on the Mac) even though it puts in the right _group_ (in Xcode). Taking care to ensure that both the folder and the group match seems to solve it, along with double-checking that the file has an ```A``` on the Xcode interface to make sure it's been added to version control.